# How to select range of dates using Selenium on Python?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to set some features on a page to download data automatically from a website. The problem is that I can't set the dates correctly from a calender.

I've tried setting the xpath, using the function 'find_element_by_xpath' but it doesn't seem to work.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


browser.get("http://www.aguacanal.es/regantes/")


select = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('sectorSelect'))
# select by visible text
select.select_by_visible_text('Sector III')

select = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('hidranteSelect'))
# select by visible text
select.select_by_visible_text('H03.156')


nav = browser.find_element_by_id('hidConDi-btn')
nav.click()



#---DatePicker
datefield = browser.find_element_by_id('hidConDi-fechaIni').click()
datefield.send_keys("01012019")
datefield = browser.find_element_by_id('hidConDi-fechaFin').click()
datefield.send_keys("03012019")
```

With this code I can select the current date, but I can't make it work correctly when I tried to set new dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply send keys to the date picker and get it to select a date.

One way is to execute JS on the page to select the dates that you want, however this is considered a bad practice.

**JS Injection Example:**

```
#---DatePicker
browser.execute_script("$('#hidConDi-fechaIni').val('01/01/2019').change();")
time.sleep(2)
browser.execute_script("$('#hidConDi-fechaFin').val('03/03/2019').change();")
```

The better way would be to automate the navigation that you would normally do to select a date in the past, however it is more complex. **[Example](http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-automating-custom-controls-datepicker/)**